# ImageMagick installation on Raspbian stretch looks installed but doesn't work

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have installed Image Magick on Raspbian Stretch:

```
uname -a
Linux eye1 4.14.34+ #1110 Mon Apr 16 00:00:00 BST 2018 armv61 GNU?Linux
```

Listing installation summary `sudo apt list --installed | grep magick`:

```
imagemagick/stable,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4 armhf [installed]
imagemagick-6-common/stable,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4 all [installed,automatic]
imagemagick-6.q16/stable,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
libmagic-mgc/stable,now 1:5.30-1+deb9u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libmagic1/stable,now 1:5.30-1+deb9u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-3/stable,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra/stable,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-6.q16-3/stable,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
```

Listing installation summary `sudo dpkg -l | grep magick`:

```
ii  imagemagick                           8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4             armhf        image manipulation programs -- binaries
ii  imagemagick-6-common                  8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4             all          image manipulation programs -- infrastructure
ii  imagemagick-6.q16                     8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4             armhf        image manipulation programs -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libmagickcore-6.q16-3:armhf           8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4             armhf        low-level image manipulation library -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra:armhf     8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4             armhf        low-level image manipulation library - extra codecs (Q16)
ii  libmagickwand-6.q16-3:armhf           8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u4             armhf        image manipulation library -- quantum depth Q16
```

But when I try to run `magick` from bash, I get `-bash: magick: command not found`. `whereis` fails to find it and there's no `man magick` either. Am I misreading the installation summary or do I need to do some other configuration step?

Comment: Just tried the same on my KDE OpenSuse Leap 42.3 i7 desktop, with similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was confused by https://imagemagick.org/script/index.php, which has `magick` as the command. Further reading (https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php circa 2005) reveals that I have commands such as `convert`, `mogrify`, ... Which **do** exist on my machine. I presume the answer is that the code was refactored from one style to the other between v6 & v7, and that raspbian uses the older style.